# Normal linear map properties

Tags: linear-algebra

So I have a test and I might need to proof the following  theorem but I can not find a proof for that so I will appreciate any help you could give.

Let $V$ be an inner product system.

Let $T:V \rightarrow V$ and we know that $T=T^{*}$

assuming that $ \forall v \in V$ $<T(v),v>=0$

$==> T = 0$

And another question I wanted to ask.

I know that if $T(v_{1})= \lambda_{1}v_{1}$ and $T^{t}(v_{2})= \lambda_{2}v_{2}$

Then $<v_{1},v_{2}>=0$.

But if $T(v_{2})= \lambda_{2}v_{2}$ is still $<v_{1},v_{2}>=0$ ?

Thanks in advanced !!

Comment: Anybody can help    ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using polarization identities for the first one.

The second assertion is true for self adjoint operators if $\lambda_{1} \neq \lambda_{2}$. See it as follows.

$$ \lambda_{1}<v_{1},v_{2}> = <\lambda_{1}v_{1},v_{2}> = <Tv_{1},v_{2}> = <v_{1},Tv_{2}> = \lambda_{2}<v_{1},v_{2}> $$ as eigenvalues of a self adjoint operators are real.

Now if $\lambda_{1} \neq \lambda_{2}$, then $<v_{1},v_{2}> = 0$.

Comment: So you are saying the second is not correct for the general case ? I mean we know that eigenvectors belongs to different eigenvalues are linear independent and from the Gram–Schmidt process we know that we give a set of linear independent we will get an orthonormal linear independent set which every vector there is eigenvector of a different eigenvalue (and we know that each vector in the set is orthogonal to the other) isn't it ?

Comment: If you use Gram-Schmidt process to a bunch of eigenvectors, you will not get eigenvectors. Also, the result is not true in general.

Comment: regarding the first one How do you proof that ? do you mean I should use trigonometric functions to proof that ?

Comment: See this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity